# enabling a dropdownlist on the selected value of another dropdownlist using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have two ASP.NET dropdownlists on my web page.The second one is disabled by default. Can anyone of you guide me to a javascript code which will enable the second dropdownlist when the selected index in the first one is "4", a clientside trigger ofcourse but i cant seem to figure it out.

I have tried the following:

`function ddlstClick() {
        if (document.getElementById("<%=ddlst_ParameterType.ClientID %>").selectedindex = "4") {
            ddlst_pulldownParameters.Enabled = true;
        }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This One.

```
var e = document.getElementById("<%=ddlst_ParameterType.ClientID %>");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;


   if (strUser == "4")
    {
     var x=document.getElementById("<%=seconddropdown.ClientID %>");
        x.disabled=false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something similar if you like to use `JQuery`

```
var value = $("#ddlst_ParameterTypeoption:selected").text();
 if (value == "4")
   $("#ddlst_pulldownParameters").attr('disabled', false);
```

Comment: thanks but i'll try this but as i am completely new to jquery it might take some time...but thanks a lot for your help